# localStorage not defined using axios interceptor in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a file called `api.js` in my root directory which takes care of calls to the external API (request and response interceptors). I am using this to inject the access_token, so my request interceptor looks like so;

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL
});

// Add request interceptor
api.interceptors.request.use(
    async config => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');

        if (token) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
        }
        config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        config.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';

        return config;
    },
    error => {
        Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

In my pages directory, i have a file called users.js ... All i want to do is return the list of users from my external API and display it in a grid when the `/users` page is loaded. My `users.js` file currently looks like so;

```
import api from "../services/api"

export default function Users() {
    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await api.get('/accounts');

}
```

But when I run this, i am getting the following error;

```
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
```

The error references the `api.js` file at the following line;

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
```

I cant seem to figure out whats going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't access local storage object on server side. It exists on browser that means client side. But your request interceptor executing on server side. So localStorage object is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in `server-side` while executing fetch in `getStaticProps()` and `localStorage` doesn't exist in server side.So if you fetch data in client side the `localStorage` will not be `undefined`.

- `getStaticProps` — fetches data at build time.
- `getStaticPaths` — pre-render dynamic routes at build time.
- `getServerSideProps` — fetches data on each request.
- `swr` — fetches data from the Client at run time.

If you need to fetch data on the client, you must use `swr`.

```
import api from "../services/api"
const fetcher = url => api.get('/accounts'); // .then(res => res.data)

function Users() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/data', fetcher)
  // ...
}
```

Check this for [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/data-fetching).

Check this [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) for `getStaticProps`.

Also check [this](https://medium.com/@binyamin/static-server-side-and-client-side-rendering-with-nextjs-d5e1c61b24bd) for more information about client side/server side fetch.

Comment: Does that mean I have to use another method than `getStaticProps()`? Is there any chance for an example, i don't really understand

Comment: You're welcome :) By the way, I don't know the next js. I recommend you to learn the client and server sides well.